# Replacement for WorkflowUtil.isStale(...)

Tags: aem

Is there a replacement for

```
com.day.cq.workflow.util.WorkflowUtil.isStale(Workflow workflow, Collection<Event> wfJobs)
```

in `com.adobe.granite.workflow`? I can't seem to find an easy way to replace this method with the newer granite workflow API.

Comment: I don't see a `WorkflowUtil` in granite workflow API. However, docs mention use of `isStaleWorkflow(Workflow workflow, Collection<Job> wfJobs)` instead of `isStale()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no directly available Util class in Granite API that gives you isStale implementation.

However in case you want alternatives, there is a method you could wrap around your own code the get the status.

```
com.adobe.granite.workflow.PayloadMap
```

This can be adapted as specified in `com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.PayloadMapFactory` 
[image: Components View of Adapter Factory]

6.1 Java Docs reference [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/) for `PayloadMap` and `Workflow`

Your method could call getWorkflowInstances to get the instance and from instance get the status by calling `getStatus()` method on `Workflow` instance.